# nginx wrong IP when checking connections limit

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have lot of times the following line appearing in the nginx error log. This is causing the 50x error appearing to the visitors of the site. We have a multilanguage site that has URL language.example.com

```
[error] 25720#0: *2716 limiting connections by zone "slimits", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: .......
```

The client is always appearing as 127.0.0.1 which is quite suspicious.

There is a load balancing in place that is using the localhost and also another server. The upstream nginx config:

```
upstream example.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:8082 weight=3 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
    server otherserver.example.net:8082 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
}
```

The slimit value is now set to 40

```
limit_conn slimits 40;
```

As far as I know this limit is supposed to be the limit of connections that a REMOTE user should be able to open. I guess that the IP address of the remote user is not passed correctly to the nginx down the line.

And this is the sites definition:

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    allow   all;
}


server {
    listen   80;
    server_name *.example.com;    
    # stop   subdomains like  everything.example.com
    deny all;
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name server.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://example.com;
    }
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name fr.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://fr.example.com;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Nginx version is: 1.0.12.

Comment: how do your slimits zone config looks like?

Comment: here is the slimts :  limit_zone slimits $binary_remote_addr 5m;

Comment: where is your `set_real_ip_from` ?

Comment: @cadmi thx that was a really good hint. I set now: real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
 and it seems that the correct address is passed in the error log [I can now see the IP that is trying to make requests instead that the usual localhost.]

Comment: @dawez and now also limits should work fine )

Answer (score 1):

OP stated [in comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/511199/using-nginx-require-authentication-when-request-from-public-ip-not-needed-when#comment577046_511199) that this setting solved the wrong IP problem.

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
```

However, the `set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0` could be troublesome in the future. Basically nginx trust all internet host for given the real IP Address via `X-Forwarded-For` header, even from spoofed request. For example (credit to [this thread](https://serverfault.com/a/525553/218590)):

```
curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4" "http://localhost/"
```

Above request was generated through curl from localhost, wasn't from nginx load balancer.

*For now the spoofing issue was little difficult because the server only sits in 127.0.0.1, but it can be security precautions.*

So, we change it so nginx only trust X-Forwarded-For from load balancer IP Address 127.0.0.1

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
```